# python telegrambot store chat id

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am wondering how I could store/read out a user chat ID to later send them messages.

Example would be, that the user is adding my telegram bot and sends him a message.
Later on in my program at some point, when a sepcific situation occurs, I want to send a message to the specific user.

For a simple example I have this code:

```
a=1
b=2

if a > b:
     # at this point python should send a message to a user via telegram privat chat

else:
    # send a different message
```

I know how to handle a response to a command sent by the user in the telegram chat, but not how to send a message to a user without receiving a command first. I think there fore I would need to have a way to store the users chat Id first to later refer to that Id when sending the message.

The point is I want to compile my program to .exe later on and send it to some friends and it should work for them as well.

Comment: You'll need to save the ID somewhere, some sort of database, or maybe an API.

Comment: I think so. I just dont know how :-)

Comment: Thats to broad as a question here on Stackoverflow. Try googling for Database tutorials, or maybe some tutorial about saving data in .exe. There should be enough starting points.